# Gradle run test task of dependency

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle

I have two gradle projects in the same directory:

```
-root: 
--projectA:
---build.gradle 
--projectB:
---build.gradle 
--build.gradle
```

ProjectA uses projectB as an implementation dependency.
How can I execute the test task of project B when project A test phase executes?

I've tried the code below but doesn't seem to work, my build files are in Kotlin DSL.

projectA build.gradle.kts:

```
tasks.test {
   ...
   useJUnitPlatform() {
     excludeTags("excluded")
   }
   failFast = true
     
   dependsOn(":projectA:test")
   }
}
```

Purpose: unit tests of dependency should also execute when unit tests of root project executes

Comment: `dependsOn(":projectA:test")` should work (don't know if it matters, but I would put it _outside_ the `useJUnitPlatform()` closure; also, note the `:` at the start of the path).

Comment: @Slaw sorry, I copied the task definition wrong. The task definition is like you told me and it still doesn't work. I edited the post to fix it, thanks for pointing out!

Comment: Ah, I think I see the problem. Based on your description, should you not be depending on the `test` task of **projectB**? i.e., `dependsOn(":projectB:test")`.